# will I get money back if I drop out of college?

Tags: university

Alright, hear me out.
it’s the *second* day of college, and I want to drop out. I never should have accepted enrollment at this college, I knew deep down for months that I didn’t want to go, but I felt pressured by my family. Is there any way that I can get my money back since I’ve only had one day of classes so far? (not to mention the first day of classes uses zero material, just purely introductions). My college is a state college (CSU). I know what path I want to take in life, and I’m already very sure that this is not the way to go. I can see how much time I’m wasting already. Please don’t answer just to tell me to stay in college, I simply want an answer.

Comment: There's more than one state university abbreviated CSU, so that detail does not really help. However, whichever CSU it is, they likely do have a tuition refund policy.

Comment: No one can answer this but your university. Policies differ. But you need to act _now_, as many policies put limits on the time for withdrawal.

Comment: @Anyon. It is likely Colorado State. Connecticut and California do not have any state universities abbreviated CSU as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Vladhagen Well, both the Connecticut State and Cal State University systems exist and can be abbreviated CSU. I was thinking more about individual universities like Cleveland State or Columbus State though. Still, I think Colorado State University has the largest enrollment, so it is a likely contender for sure. Either way, the abbreviation is very overloaded...

Comment: @Anyon I will grant you that much. I overlooked the fact that their are state universities not named [U.S. State] State.

Answer (score 4):

It is common that universities will refund a almost all of the tuition you have paid if you withdraw from the university within the first week. It is often gradated after that, with a smaller percentage of tuition and fees being returned the later you wait to withdraw.

If you attend Colorado State University (CSU?), then it looks like you can still get 75% of your money back. They give you until September 2 to withdraw and get 75% back. The first day of school was the deadline to get 100% tuition back. You would need to talk with the registrar's office directly about all of this though.

https://registrar.colostate.edu/faculty-staff/important-dates/

Comment: My school doesn't even make tuition due until like the fourth week of the quarter